# Possible to see total reputation from one post?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Wondering if it's possible to see total amount of reputation over time generated by one post for a given user.

Note that it's not simple upvotes * 10 - downvotes * 2 math - there is a cap of 200 daily reputation.

Comment: There's two different definitions of "reputation from one post" due to the repcap. One definition is: If you moved the post to a new account. How much rep would that new account have? The other definition is: If you removed the post from the account, how much rep would the user lose.

Comment: You can use [`http://stackoverflow.com/reputation`](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ That one gives the second definition as per my first comment. I've always wondered if there was an easier way to query for the first definition. (I'm not good enough with SQL to write one from the data explorer from scratch.)

Comment: @Mysticial Not really. For example, say you posted two answers on the same day and both of them got 20 votes on that day. Removing either of them wouldn't affect your reputation, but `/reputation` might tell a different story.

Comment: Oh right, that rep-page would give a number somewhere in between the two extremes. Take Jon Skeet's top answer would be the most extreme example. By the first definition, the new account would have about 20k rep. By the second definition, He only gained 15 rep from it.

Comment: @djechlin Just to clarify, which definition do you want? Or the in-between definition that the /reputation page would give. Not that I have a way to query for any of them though.

Comment: @Mysticial - the latter is what I was thinking of.  I suppose for the most part the former merely caps the post @ 200 rep per day.  The latter I think would actually double-count rep between two questions as if I have great answer A and B that received 200 points per day on the same day and either is deleted there would be no rep drop.  But this is more of a "just curious" thing so for me imprecision is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate this pretty easily if you have sufficient reputation to view the vote breakdown.

If you have more than 1000 rep on the specific Stack Exchange site, you can view how many upvotes or downvotes were cast by clicking on the number next to the post. A downvote costs the owner of the post 2 reputation, while an upvote gives a person 10 reputation. So for example this post earned me `(2 x -2) + (2 x 10) = 16` rep:

[image]

If you have < 1000 rep, you could use the ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) userscript / Chrome extension.

Comment: Don't at all understand how to do that.

Comment: You also need to take into account the repcap.

Comment: @Mysticial True. Don't think that is possible with the existing tools.

Comment: @Asad Use `/reputation`

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Doesn't that only work for you?

Comment: @Asad Yes. If you wanted to see it for some other user you'd have to go through their reputation history.